# What is the difference between "with the times" and "with time"

Tags: differences

I am making this statement:

`Indeed, the cloud computing grows in different stages with the times...`

and I am not sure about the difference between "**with the times**" with "s" and "**with time**" without "s" and the definite article "the".

The meaning that I want to give is that "Cloud computing" is growing in different phases/stages and I will enumerate details later in the paragraph.

Thanks

Comment: Did you make, I don't know, *any* attempt to look this up on your own?

Comment: yes `make`, and I did my own research

Comment: *[with the times](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/time#time__16)* vs *[with time](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/time#time__2)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"With time" means proportional to the passage of time.  So if you say that cloud computing grows with time, you mean that there will be more cloud computing in the future.

"With the times" means in accordance with the era.  So if you say that cloud computing grows with the times, you mean that cloud computing is one increasingly-used component in an era of remote-storage cyber-operation.